# Email multiple user selected pages

Tags: 7, emails

I need a way where someone can visit multiple nodes, add them to a list, and email them in a batch / list to a person.  I've looked at ShareThis and AddToAny, and each would seem to do a fine job for a single page, but I need to be able to collect an arbitrary number of pages and then forward them via email when the client is done creating the list.

The "use case" is that a salesman will visit a store, select 3 or 4 items on an iPhone / iPad that they would like to send more information on, and use Drupal to create the list and send the email.

I'm trying to avoid custom coding a solution because my skills are not quite up to the task, and as with everything, deadlines are tight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) or [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) and the [Printer, e-mail and PDF versions](http://drupal.org/project/print) Modules

Comment: So, I'm tweaking the flag module, and I can see how I can allow users to basically create a "bucket", and I can use VBO to allow them to remove all of the flagged nodes.

Now to figure out how to email a list.

Comment: Place the print module block on your flag views for your users to send.